# How can I force woocommerce to use https in all urls?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https, woocommerce

I have purchased SSL certs and done all the necessary work to get the cert files onto my server and into my apache config files for my virtualhost.

In WP in the backend I have made sure my urls all use https: in them and forced the wp backend to always use https. This all works fine but issues start happening on some pages where it says that it cannot be found giving a 404 error and specifically on the woocommerce /cart and /checkout pages which is really bizarre.

I have even stripped out the settings to force https in site urls and gone straight into .htaccess and forced https throughout the whole site and even still I get errors on /cart and /checkout.

I have permalinks in WP set to custom and custom base url of /shop in woocommerce.

Has anyone else had this issue with woocommerce?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer…